# Do applications for postdocs get rejected if they don't have a minimum number of publications?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, early-career

If you don't have a certain minimum number of published papers, will that be used to reject applicants in the first round? Is that common?

Comment: No real rules about the number of papers, it is really up to the PI

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how many applications a position gets and the publication tradition of the discipline. When a position attracts hundreds of applications, then there are often quick and dirty rules applied to bring that number down to something manageable. This could include the number of publications. Though I suspect that it won't be a hard rule in the sense that not having x publications means you are in the discard pile. Instead you would end up lower on priority pile. In such a highly competitive environment the end effect will often be the same though.

However there are many positions that are not that competitive, and I would not expect that publications would be the main criterium at such an early stage of the career. Publishing takes time, so early in the career a person hasn't had the time.

Comment: A _criterium_ is a bicycle race. The singular of _criteria_ is _criterion._

Answer (score 5):

There is no general rule for this. The hiring decision for post-docs is essentially up to the PI. They will be looking for the best candidate for the project, however they define that. Factors which could be important include:

- Research experience
- Experience with a particular piece of equipment/software/technique relevant to the project
- Good reference letters/recommendations from researchers the PI knows/respects
- Quality/quantity of publications
- PI's familiarity with the potential post-doc
- etc

Different PIs will weigh these factors differently. For me personally, number of publications is pretty low on the list of important criteria. Ultimately they can only choose from whomever applies, so always apply if you're interested.

Comment: Note that not all postdocs answer to a PI. It is field dependent and the notion of a PI is foreign to some. It might be a departmental decision, not an individual one. But, yes, a variety of criteria is more likely than a single one.